# Send POST parameters to Voice URL for incoming calls with Twilio

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm allowing my site to accept incoming calls with python and javascript. I want to make sure that whoever answers the call has their username logged correctly by Twilio. As posted in their [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/incoming-calls) you need to create a capability token to accept incoming calls:

```
capability.allow_client_outgoing(application_sid)
capability.allow_client_incoming("jenny")
```

There could be up to 20 different users on the site at once that could answer the call so I would want the `"jenny"` string to be replaced to allow a dynamic username based upon who is logged in.

I'm using Django as my framework and generate the token through a view that request the username from `request.user.username`

```
def token(request):                                                                            

    capability = TwilioCapability(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    capability.allow_client_outgoing(APP_ID)                                                                    
    capability.allow_client_incoming(request.user.username)     

    token = capability.generate()                                                                                            
    data =  json.dumps({'token': token})                                                                                                                         

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

My Twilio Voice URL gets directed to this function. If it does not see a `phone_number` parameter then it can assume it is a incoming call. I somehow want to send the 'call_rep' parameter through this post which will match up the usernames to allow the incoming call with the correct user information:

```
@twilio_view                                                             
def make_call(request):                                                  
    resp = Response()                                                                                                      

    if 'phone_number' in request.POST:                                   
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']                                                                                                  
        resp.say("Making the call now")                                  
        resp.dial(number=phone_number, callerId=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER)     

    else:                                                                

        resp.say("Incoming call")                                                                                        
        with resp.dial(callerId=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER) as r:               
            r.client(request.POST['call_rep'])                                                         

    return resp
```

Is there somewhere in my JavaScript I need to put the `call_rep`'s username in?

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token);

Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {           
});                                               

Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {            
        console.log(error);                       
    $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);    
});                                               

Twilio.Device.offline(function(device) {          
    // Called on network connection lost.         
});                                               

Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {           
    console.log("Successfully established call"); 
});                                               

Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {        
    // Called for all disconnections              
    console.log('DISCONNECT: ' + conn.status);    
});                                               

/* Listen for incoming connections */             

Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {          
        connection = conn 
        connection.accept()
});
```

For outgoing calls I can pass extra parameters no problems. How do I do this with incoming?

```
Twilio.Device.connect({                       
    call_rep: '{{ request.user.username }}',  
    phone_number: phone_number                
});
```

Comment: Hey Austin, Twilio employee here. I'm actually writing an article on using the request parameters with Client at the moment. Can I just clear a few things up? You're able to pass these params with outgoing calls, but not incoming? Do you mean Outgoing from the Client app?

Comment: Correct, I am able to pass parameters from the client app for outgoing calls. I use this so the function in my Twilio Voice URL will call the correct number. I should have noted I'm essiently trying to build a call center where any representative could answer the incoming call. I was trying to find a way to pass the representatives name to my Twilio URL so it would accept the connection. I have since tried to work around this issue by using a Queue. Although I now have the problem having trying to contact the representatives if a caller is in the queue. I'm looking at pusher or Socket.IO now.